# Whats the best way to show "distance" from Point A to Point B

Tags: ux-designer, lean-ux, ux-integration

Below theres a SCREENSHOT (Not real scale/sizes) of a material design card (close and open) that fill a Feed of actual events in a city, recently we discover that people wants to know how far are they from the event so we are adding the Distance field on the card.... is there a method for this or i just copy google maps patterns for this?

I would like to add that i don't have permission to reveal more than this.

[image: Close]
[image: Open]

Comment: That bar is 10 blocks from my home ;)

Comment: @Devin well follow sencilloes on Instagram we have a surprise for Buenos Aires in a few days.

Comment: Why not just show the distance there at the bottom with the other info? "The Temple Bar - The House - Godoy cruz 1853 - 4.5 mi"

Comment: @KenMohnkern thats sort of what im thinking i just want to double check... i was thinking on doing that but on the title and align it to the left.

Comment: That seems the standard way of handling it. Look at Foursquare, Tinder, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If it's in a major city show distances in terms of how many blocks.

Possible options:

-Walking time in minutes

-Biking time in minutes

-Driving time in minutes

Give the user the ability to sort/filter events by distance if you discover users prefer events nearby.

Answer (score 0):

Is this meant to be a printed card that's mailed out, or a virtual card that's e-mailed out?

If it's a printed card that's mailed to a specific set of people, you could overprint the card with a geolocated distance ("You live only 6.5 km away!").  A similar trick could work for an e-mailed card, if you know the physical addresses of the recipients.

If you don't know their physical addresses, of course, your only recourse is to print the location of the venue and hope they'll work out the distance for themselves.

Comment: No its not meant to be printed, as i said this is a Material Design card... heres the link if you want to read more about Material Design https://material.google.com

Comment: Ah, thanks. This is the first I've heard of that buzzword.  Corporations almost always try to colonise general words like "material" and give them a proprietary meaning.  It reduces the ability of people to use the words in the original context.